# Gauss-Seidel matrix iteration

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have this matrix:

```
> mat <- matrix(c( rep(1:12,1)), 4, 4)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9    1
[2,]    2    6   10    2
[3,]    3    7   11    3
[4,]    4    8   12    4
```

I want to replace the middle 4 values using the average of surrounded elements; I can do it using:

```
for (i in 1:1000){
  mat[2,2]=  (mat[1,2] + mat[2,1] + mat[3,2] + mat[2,3])/4
  mat[2,3]=  (mat[2,2] + mat[2,4] + mat[1,3] + mat[3,3])/4
  mat[3,2]=  (mat[3,1] + mat[3,3] + mat[2,2] + mat[4,2])/4
  mat[3,3]=  (mat[3,2] + mat[3,4] + mat[4,3] + mat[2,3])/4
  print(mat)
}
```

My question is: how I can turn this into a function so that I can I apply it directly to selected matrix elements (i.e. `mat[2:3,2:3]`)?

Comment: Why are you using loop here?

Comment: I'm using loops because I want to predict those values based on the surrounded elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GSfun <- function(M, r, c) {sum(matrix(c(0,1,0,
                                         1,0,1,
                                         0,1,0), 3) * 
                                 M[r+(-1:1),c+(-1:1)]) /4 }

for (i in 2:3){ for (j in 2:3){  mat[i,j] <- GSfun(mat, i,j)}}
mat
     [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5  9.00    1
[2,]    2    6  7.00    2
[3,]    3    7  7.25    3
[4,]    4    8 12.00    4
for (i in 2:3){ for (j in 2:3){  mat[i,j] <- GSfun(mat, i,j)}}
mat
     [,1]  [,2]    [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1 5.000  9.0000    1
[2,]    2 5.250  5.8750    2
[3,]    3 5.875  6.6875    3
[4,]    4 8.000 12.0000    4
```

Iterative application until sum of absolute deviations less than 0.01:

```
 maxiter = 20; n=1; repeat { n=n+1; 
     diverg <- sum(abs(mat[2:3, 2:3])); 
     for (i in 2:3){ for (j in 2:3){  mat[i,j] <- GSfun(mat, i,j)}}; 
     if ( n>maxiter | (diverg - sum(abs(mat[2:3, 2:3])) < 0.01) ) {break}  }
 n
# [1] 8
 mat
#------------
     [,1]     [,2]      [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1 5.000000  9.000000    1
[2,]    2 4.500732  5.500366    2
[3,]    3 5.500366  6.500183    3
[4,]    4 8.000000 12.000000    4
```

Comment: Thanks @DWin , I have the same question that I asked Henrik. Each time you run this function on your matrix you get different results until the values don't change that much. So I need to run this for n number of times to get a reliable prediction.

Comment: I showed you what happens with 2 repeated applications. What are you asking? Are you hoping to get automatic reapplication until a convergence criterion is met. If so, then you need to express your expectations more clearly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you wanted to wrap that `repeat` call inside a function it should be trivial to encapsulate it.

Comment: For any reason I got an error, I'll get back to it tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just ran it again using the code I posted and had no error. Just incase there were an error in the iterative application I copy-pasted that code from my console.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# a matrix with slightly 'simpler' numbers
set.seed(1)
mm <- matrix(sample(1:3, 16, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4)
mm

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    2    3
# [2,]    2    3    1    2
# [3,]    2    3    1    3
# [4,]    3    2    1    2

f_replace <- function(mm, rows, cols){
  mm2 <- mm
  for(i in rows){
    for(j in cols){
      rows_around <- i + c(0, 0, -1, 1)
      cols_around <- j + c(-1, 1, 0, 0)
      id <- cbind(rows_around, cols_around)
      mm2[i, j] <- mean(mm[id])
    }
  }
  return(mm2)
}

f_replace(mm, 2:3, 2:3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1 1.00    2    3
# [2,]    2 1.75    2    2
# [3,]    2 2.00    2    3
# [4,]    3 2.00    1    2

# a loop where you can plug in your n of choice
for(i in n){
  mm <- f_replace(mm, 2:3, 2:3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks the function is what I wanted but can I add a loop so that it iterate over the new values for n number of times?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please try to explain with a tiny example. But please avoid that your question becomes a moving target.

Comment: The idea is that values of concern in the matrix can be predicted using the average of the surrounded cells. Those values `mat[2:3,2:3])` are potential guesses, so the program each time replaces the new values until that recommended values don't change a lot. In my example I ran the program for 1000 times `for (i in 1:1000)`. I wanted to add the same thing in your code.

Comment: OK. I think I get it. Sorry, I missed (supressed?) the iteration part when I read your question. I assume you 'just' need to copy the output matrix mm2 to mm in the end of the function, and run the function again with that updated mm. But it is getting a bit late here, so I can't do much about it right now...

Comment: Just added a very simple loop. But I agree with @DWin, which is your convergence criterion? I can't get any further now. I have to refer you to his answer.